# HTML Agility pack + Select node by its inner text

Tags: c#-4.0, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have gotten the hang of using the html agility pack to find specific nodes using their attributes and xpaths. The problem is, I've been doing this manually for each of my projects (opening the website html and scanning for the nodes that have the text i need). Is there a way to select a single node by its inner text? This would make it easier to write an update script for websites whose content scheme is the same, but attribute tags change values over time. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

Would be better if you have provided sample HTML, but since you haven't, let's assume we have HTML containing this markup :

```
<body>
    <div class="foo">bar</div>
</body>
```

You can select the `<div>` by it's attribute using HtmlAgilityPack's `SelectSingleNode()` and XPath like so :

```
myHtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='foo']");
```

or you can select the same by the inner text like so :

```
myHtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[.='bar']");
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Such a simple solution! I didn't realize you could use an xpath to find the text of the node directly. Every example i saw showed methods to get to the text you wanted, but not the other way around. Thank you @har07, that was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Why the downvote, care to explain? Maybe you think about something like `//div[text()='bar']` rather than `//div[.='bar']`, no?

Comment: @har07 how would you edit the content/value/src of the div?